# Palindromic representation in base $x$ and Integer factoring

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, factoring, palindromic-polynomials

If $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is representable as the product of two palindromic integers in base $x$. i.e.,

$$
\begin{align}
n &= (x^4+px^3+qx^2+px+1)(x^4+rx^3+sx^2+rx+1) \newline
  &=x^8+x^7 (p + r)+x^6 (p r + q + s)+ x^5 (p (s + 1)+ q r + r) \newline & + x^4 (2 p r + q s + 2) + x^3 (p (s + 1)+ q r + r) \newline &+ x^2 (p r + q + s)+ x (p + r)+ 1 \newline
  &=x^8+ax^7+bx^6+cx^5+dx^4+cx^3+bx^2+ax+1,
\end{align} \tag{1}
$$

then $n$ itself is a palindromic integer in base $x$ such that

$$
\begin{align}
a &=p+r \newline
b &=pr+q+s \newline
c &=ps+qr+p+r \newline
d &=2pr+qs+2.
\end{align} \tag{2}
$$

For a base-$x$ representation, the condition $0 \le a,b,c,d \lt x$ holds. We relax this condition and let $a,b,c,d$ be any integer and call such a representation as a palindromic extended base-$x$ representation.

Suppose we are given an odd integer $n$ and we want to find a palindromic extended base-$x$ representation of degree-$8$ as given in Eqn. (1) with $a, b, c, d, x \in \mathbb{Z}.$ How would we go about that?

**Approach tried so far:**
Treating $a,b,c,d$ as variables and $x$ as a parameter, we have

$$(x^8+1)+a(x^7+x)+b(x^6+x^2 )+c(x^5+x^3 )+dx^4=n$$

i.e.,

$$a(x^7+x)+b(x^6+x^2 )+c(x^5+x^3 )+dx^4=n-x^8-1 \tag{3}$$

i.e.,

$$x|(n-x^8-1)$$

1. $x=1$ divides $n-x^8-1$. Therefore, $x=-1$ also divides $n-x^8-1$.
2. Since $n$ is odd, $x=2$ gives $n-2^8-1$, an even number which is divisible by $2$. Therefore, $x=-2$ also divides $n-2^8-1$.

i.e., $x \in \{\pm 1, \pm 2\}$ gives us a system of equations

$$
\begin{align}
2a+2b+2c+d &=n-2 \newline
-2a+2b-2c+d &=n-2 \newline
130a+66b+40c+16d &=n-257 \newline
-130a+66b-40c+16d &=n-257 \newline
\end{align} \tag{4}
$$

However, this doesn't necessarily give us integer solutions for $a, b, c, d$.

How does one choose $x$ so that we get integer solutions for $a,b,c,d$ in Eqn. $(3)$?

Bonus question: Suppose we choose $x$ such that $a,b,c,d$ are integers. What is the necessary and sufficient condition such that $p, q, r, s$ are integers? Note that this is equivalent to a factoring method for $n$.

**Related:**

[Solving a particular system of Diophantine equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4571157/solving-a-particular-system-of-diophantine-equations)

[Factoring palindromic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568054/factoring-palindromic-polynomial)

Comment: You ask for a  palindromic extended bas-$x$ representation for $n$ as in $(1)$, which reads
$$(x^4+px^3+qx^2+px+1)(x^4+rx^3+sx^2+rx+1).$$
This presupposes that the first and last digit of both palindromic factors equals $1$. Is that really a restriction that you want? And to be clear, do you also allow $p,q,r,s\in\Bbb{Z}$ to be *any* integer, or do you only allow $a,b,c,d,x\in\Bbb{Z}$ to be any integer and require that $0\leq p,q,r,s<x$?

Comment: @Servaes : The leading monomial of the palindromic polynomial has coefficient $1$. The only other restriction is $a,b,c,d,p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$. The motivation for this problem is to factor $n$ by finding a degree-8 palindromic polynomial representation denoted by the quadruple $(a,b,c,d)$. I do not not know if that there exists a degree-$8$ palindromic polynomial representation for every integer $n$ that gives such a factorization.

Comment: Well if you take $x=1$ you get
$$2+2a+2b+2c+d=n,$$
which clearly has infinitely many solutions. In fact for any choice of $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Z}$ you can pick $d\in\Bbb{Z}$ accordingly. The same is true for $x=-1$. Are you looking for other solutions?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The solutions we are looking for should also satisfy $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\in\Bbb{Z}$ be given. You want to find $p,q,r,s,x\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that
$$n=(x^4+px^3+qx^2+px+1)(x^4+rx^3+sx^2+rx+1).$$
Taking $x=1$ simplifies this to
$$n=(2p+q+2)(2r+s+2),$$
and so we may take any factorization $n=uv$ and any $p,r\in\Bbb{Z}$ and set
$$q:=u-2p-2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad s:=v-2r-2.$$